# Launching an executable via a QGIS plugin with Python

Tags: pyqgis, python-3.7

I developed a plugin on QGIS 2.18 in Python 2 (which works in a Linux environment) and I'm trying today to convert my code to Python3 so that I can use it on QGIS 3.18 and directly in a Windows environment.

My plugin retrieves text information that the user fills in, and executes an .exe with `subprocess.popen` function and that's where I get stuck

```py
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['Traitement_2.exe', r"cd C:/Users/Utilisateur/Traitement"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,encoding = "ISO-8859-1", shell=True, text=True) print(proc.stdout) 
while True:
    lecture = proc.stdout.readline()
    print (lecture)
    if 'FIN' in lecture:
        print('Le Traitement est fini')
        break
```

If I run this Python code in a Windows command prompt (by doing `python test_py2.py`), my program `Traitement_2.exe` runs and returns strings of characters (and only strings of characters) displayed in the console like this:

[output image of my script test_py2.py[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeQsE.png)`

But when I put this code in my plugin.py (QGIS plugin), nothing starts. I don't get an error either, I just have the impression that nothing happens. The read variable is of type but is empty.

Do you have a solution or something to think about?

Comment: Try [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: You can also do `import os` then `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path/to/directory/to/Traitement/exe`. It may not work just because it does not found the executable `Traitement_2.exe` in the PATH

Comment: @ThomasG77 I don't understand

Comment: When you execute an exe, if it's not in the PATH environment variable, it will not found it. So, add the path to be sure the exe will be found. Read https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them